# kubernetes connect to node postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, kubernetes

I have 1 DPS with Ubuntu, I have installed postgres on the node and kubernates
Now I have a pod (or more than 1) that needs to connect to postgres
I have already edited postgres configuration to accept any inbound connection but the pod can't connect to the db, I get connection refused (socket exception)

as connection string I use:

```
host=<nodeip>;database=<db>;username=<usr>;password=<pwd>;
```

any idea?

postgres status

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-08-10 16:49:15 CEST; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 31145 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Aug 10 16:49:15 puck466 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Aug 10 16:49:15 puck466 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

netstat output:

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     84378715 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     84378719 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             puck466.startdedicated.net  tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:postgresql state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  10.244.0.0/16        anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.244.0.0/16

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000
DROP       all  -- !127.0.0.0/8          127.0.0.0/8          /* block incoming localnet connections */ ! ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-PROXY-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.100.159.214       /* default/portalapi-service-ext: has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:http-alt reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.97.176.106        /* default/portalapi-service: has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:http-alt reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: What exactly is `clusterip`? You should probably use the node IP.

Comment: yes it is the node ip, also externally I get same error... maybe I missed something in postgres or firewall?

Comment: What Kubernetes distribution do you have and how did you install it?

Comment: I have installed thought apt-get following the tutorial on kubernates doc
EDIT: i can access pgsql trough installed pgadmin4 with address localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two versions of postgres on my node machine
so the steps:

- uninstall all postgres
- install postgresql-12
- edit pg_hba.conf adding: host all all all trust
- edit postgresql.conf and set listen_addr='*'
- restart postgresql

WORKS!